# How to hide headers when packaging static library?

Tags: iphone

I want to put my private headers into my static library, so the customers can only see the public headers and .a file, but setting the headers "private" when packaging the library didn't work. Adding only the public headers and source files(.a) to the customer's project would cause errors:the “private” headers not found...Any help please?

Comment: Which errors are being caused?

Comment: @MattP The “private” headers not found,since I only copy the public headers to the costomer's project

Comment: @MattP I want to put my private headers into my static library, so the customers can only see the public ones, but setting the headers "private" when packaging the library didn't work. Adding only the public headers and source files(.a) to the customer's project would cause errors:the “private” headers not found. ps: 3x for your help MattP :)

Answer (score 1):

Without anything concrete to go on, I can describe what I have run into in the past. Your .h files are possibly using `#import` with references to your private headers. You will need to move those to your .m files. If this causes issues in your .h files due to undeclared classes, etc., you will have to do forward declarations with `@class` or other similar techniques.

Comment: Glad it helped. You can do the same with `@protocol` as needed.

Comment: For whomever asked the question.. please mark this answer!! it is awesome!